# Vue JS click.shift.exact not working with SVG?

Tags: svg, vue.js

When using the .exact modifier on the @click event I'm not getting the expected behaviour on SVG elements.

```
  <circle
      @click.shift.exact="onShiftClick"
      @click.exakt="onClick"          
      cx="50"
      cy="50"
      r="10"
      stroke="#2f9aff"
      stroke-width="0.5"
      fill="#212529">
  </circle>
```

Holding down shift and clicking causes BOTH the onShiftClick and onClick to be called. Am I doing something wrong or is this a bug? JS Fiddle here that includes HTML buttons that work as expected: https://jsfiddle.net/80Lpu1cb/3/

Comment: Looks like you have a typo: `@click.exakt` should be `@click.exact`. Fixed: [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/wsg0t453/)

Comment: GAH! Thanks! Now, where did I put my glasses?